# Is there a way to redefine options set in a lua setup{} call without calling setup again?

Tags: neovim, plugin

I'm trying to customize a plugin and I want to know if there's a way to just set a single option without calling setup, or to change an option after setup has been called.

```
local actions = require('telescope.actions')
local telescope = require('telescope')

telescope.setup{
    pickers = {
        find_files = {
            hidden = true,
            find_command = {
                'rg',
                '--color=never',
                '--files',
                '--no-ignore',
                '--iglob',
                '!.git',
                '--iglob',
                '!node_modules/**/*',
                '--iglob',
                '!.idea/',
                '--iglob',
                '!dist/'
            }
        }
    },
    defaults = {
        mappings = {
            i = {
                ["<A-j>"] = function () actions.move_selection_next(vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()) end,
                ["<A-k>"] = function () actions.move_selection_previous(vim.api.nvim_get_current_buf()) end
            }
        },
        vimgrep_arguments = {
            'rg',
            '--color=never',
            '--no-heading',
            '--with-filename',
            '--line-number',
            '--column',
            '--smart-case',
            '--iglob',
            '!.git',
            '--iglob',
            '!node_modules/**/*',
            '--iglob',
            '!.idea/',
            '--iglob',
            '!dist/',
            '-u'
        },

    }
}

telescope.load_extension('projects')
```

Is there an way to change the find_files setting, ideally using lua, without calling setup again? A use case would be changing a single setting if a certain file is opened.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! My intuition is that each lua plugin provides it's own `setup` function, which _happens_ (?) to be a convention, not a requirement. So for each plugin you would need to find out what is available to dynamically adjust any settings.

Comment: That is my understanding as well. I thought there _might_ be a similar convention for changing settings. In the case of telescope, the only other option I could find is passing custom arguments to the commands on each call, which isn't ideal.

Comment: For the settings you’ve posted, you might be interested in learning how to use the default vimgrep and grep commands. Especially the latter can be customized using grepprg to use, eg, ripgrep (which is what i do)